# sendKeys() does not work with the table column webelement

Tags: selenium

**Problem:** Not able to use sendKeys in table.

**What am i doing:** I have table created from dojo. Able to get the columns and when i print them i can see the values of each column. i want to set value for a column, which is 2nd in my case as some value, i want to set it to "testselenium" string. sendkeys works normally but not in this particular case.

I am using Java to use selenium for testing.

Following is the piece of code which i am trying to use.

```
<pre><code>

    List<WebElement> findElements = driver
            .findElement( By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id,'mytable')]"))
            .findElement( By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class,'dojoxGridContent')]"))
            .findElements(By.tagName("td"));

    // Got the column elements

    Iterator<WebElement> iterator = findElements.iterator();
    int counter = 0;
    // Iterating over column i.e. td elements
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        counter++;
        WebElement next = iterator.next();
        if(counter == 2){
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.doubleClick(next);
            action.perform();
            next.sendKeys("testselenium");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(next.getText());
    }

</pre></code>
```

Does anybody has idea on the same.

Comment: does it actually doubleclick? I feel like in this case you neet to make it available first ... so possible adding some wait?

Comment: If it is a text field, you can directly use clear() and then sendKeys() without using Actions. Can you please let us know, why there is a need to use doubleclick?

Comment: <pre>if(counter == 2){
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);              action.doubleClick(next);                        action.sendKeys("testselenium");
            action.perform();

            break;
        }     </pre>        using sendKeys from action before perform call did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
if(counter == 2){
Actions action = new Actions(driver);              
action.doubleClick(next);                        
**action.sendKeys("testselenium");**
action.perform();
break;
}     
</pre>
```

using sendKeys from action before perform call did the trick for me.